# How to link two unrelated classes in C++ free function using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, metaprogramming

I have a serialization streaming operator as a free function like this:

```
struct MyClass { 
    static size_t size() { return 24; } // whatever my expected size is
    X x; Y y; 
};
Archive& operator<<(Archive& ar, MyClass& c) {
    ar << c.x;
    ar << c.y;
    return ar;
}
```

I have lots of classes and and free function operators like this.

I would like to add a `static_assert` compile-time check that will fire automatically to do a size check on MyClass (for the case where some developer has added a field to MyClass and forgotten to serialize it).  It will call `MyClass::size()` to get the expected size and compare against `sizeof(MyClass)`.

I don't want to change all the `operator<<` definitions to do this.  It's tedious, error-prone and it won't implement the original intent: to automatically run the check without having the developer to explicitly write the check (since that'll never happen).  Also, the serialization code is from a library, so I don't want to change the original code.

I was thinking that--with metaprogramming--I can let Archive know that I'm serializing MyClass.  Then it can do a check like this:

```
static_assert(sizeof(MyClass) == MyClass::size();
```

But how to do this?  If I make Archive expect a template parameter whose value is MyClass, then every line in the operator<< will have to change since each ar will be an instance of a different class:

```
Archive<MyClass>& operator<<(Archive<MyClass>& ar, MyClass& c) {
    Archive<X> arX;  arX << c.x;
    Archive<Y> arY;  arY << c.y;
    return ar;
}
```

Any brilliant ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: The trouble with this scheme is that a person going to update `MyClass` might bump the size whether or not they update the serializer. Is updating the _signature_ of the floating operators, while leaving the definition alone, an option?

Comment: Well I *do* want them to update the serializer if they bump the size. How would you update the signature of the floating serializers to force them to update the serializer when they bump the size?  (These operators can’t take any more arguments. ) Have them take a template parameter?  Would you give an example?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this is only effective if the constant comes from the overload, and you can't snuff the error without updating the overload specifically instead of some class method.

But as you mentioned, you can't add an argument to the `<<` operator. Let's try anyway, since you hinted that you can update the signature, by converting it to a function:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
using ExpectedSize = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

Archive& Serialize(Archive& ar, MyClass& c, ExpectedSize<24>) {
    ar << c.x;
    ar << c.y;
    return ar;
}
```

Then, invoke that from a catch-all overload:

```cpp
template <typename T>
Archive& operator <<(Archive ar, T&& c) {
    return Serialize(ar, c, ExpectedSize<sizeof(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type)>{});
}
// non-template overloads for basic primitives
Archive& operator <<(Archive& ar, int c) { return ar; }
Archive& operator <<(Archive& ar, const char* c) { return ar; }
```

Now, when you run the code and `sizeof(MyClass) == 16` instead of 24, you get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Serialize(Archive&, MyClass&, ExpectedSize<16>)'
...
note: candidate: 'Archive& Serialize(Archive&, MyClass&, ExpectedSize<24>)'
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/sBFtBR

If you really wanted a more specific error message, you can add a template to catch the missing overloads:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
Archive& Serialize(Archive& ar, T&& c, ExpectedSize<N>) {
    static_assert(sizeof(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type) != N, "Serializer needs to be updated");
}
```

Then your error message becomes:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'Archive& Serialize(Archive&, T&&, ExpectedSize<N>) [with T = MyClass&; long unsigned int N = 16; ExpectedSize<N> = std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 16>]':
<source>:11:21:   required from 'Archive& operator<<(Archive, T&&) [with T = MyClass&]'
<source>:40:12:   required from here
<source>:34:67: error: static assertion failed: Serializer needs to be updated
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/wQAvGg

Comment: This is very good. Thanks man!  It solves the problem in an elegant way.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a bit more, it doesn't meet one of my objectives.  The problem is that the developer who's creating a new class will have to write the Serialize routine.  And he could just forget about the ExpectedSize parameter and not implement it.  In my approach, where the class constructor does the static_assert, there's no way for them to avoid it.

Comment: In my approach, if the class constructor does the static_assert, there's no way for them to avoid it.  But it has the ugliness of having to convert between `Archive<X>` and `Archive<Y>`.

Comment: Here's what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Since your final goal is to enforce consistency between serialization functions and class definitions, you may as well consider automatic generation of serialization methods. This would be more involved than the accepted answer, but may save you some time in long term. I know of two approaches both of which require some nasty tricks: one relies on wrapper classes as descibed here http://cplusplus.bordoon.com/dark_side.html, another is to use xmacro technique  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro to be able to do something like this in the end -> https://github.com/asherikov/ariles#example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.  Basically I uses @parktomatomi's idea of a user-written `Serialize` routine, but now it gets called by a catch-all 
`template<class T> operator<<(Archive&, T& c)`
that also does the `static_assert` for the size check.

```
struct B {
  constexpr static size_t size() { return 20; }
  int y = 200;
};

struct C {
  constexpr static size_t size() { return 10; }
  int x = 100;
  B b;
};

template<typename T>
Archive& Serialize(Archive& ar, T& c) {
  abort();  // Should never get here
}

Archive& operator <<(Archive& ar, int x) {
  std::cout << "ar << " << x << std::endl;
  return ar;
}

template <typename T>
Archive& operator <<(Archive& ar, T& c) {
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == T::size());
  return Serialize<T>(ar, c);
}

template<>
Archive& Serialize(Archive& ar, B& b) {
  std::cout << "ar<B> << " << b.y << std::endl;
  ar << b.y;
  return ar;
}
template<>
Archive& Serialize(Archive& ar, C& c) {
  std::cout << "ar<B> << " << c.x << std::endl;
  ar << c.b;
  ar << c.x;
  return ar;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Archive ar;
  C c;
  ar << c;

  //std::cout << foo(2);
}
```

It produces

```
a.cpp: In instantiation of âArchive& operator<<(Archive&, T&) [with T = B]â:
a.cpp:91:11:   required from here
a.cpp:77:27: error: static assertion failed
   static_assert(sizeof(T) == T::size());
                 ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp: In instantiation of âArchive& operator<<(Archive&, T&) [with T = C]â:
a.cpp:100:9:   required from here
a.cpp:77:27: error: static assertion failed
```

Now I need to come up with a better message.